# get array.length without a getter from other contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-invocation, contract-debugging

Is there a way to get length of an array in an other contract without a getter?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract MyContractA {
    uint[] public myArray;

    function MyContractA() {
        myArray.length = 1;
    }

}

contract MyContractB {

    function test() returns (uint ret) {
        address instanceAddress = new MyContractA();
        MyContractA instance = MyContractA(instanceAddress);
        // works:
        return instance.myArray(0); 
        //
        // doesn't work: 
        //
        //  TypeError: Member "length" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in function (uint256) constant external returns (uint256)
        // return instance.myArray.length;

        // TypeError: Member "length" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in function (uint256) constant external returns (uint256)
        // return instance.myArray.length();

        //   TypeError: Wrong argument count for function call: 0 arguments given but expected 1.
        //return instance.myArray().length;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No. You need to present a function that will return the array length as a `uint`.

Something like

```
function getCount() public view returns(uint count) {
    return array.length;
}
```

It's a pretty common requirement. These storage patterns might save you some time working out how to do things within the constraints we're dealing with: [Are there well-solved and simple storage patterns for Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13167/are-there-well-solved-and-simple-storage-patterns-for-solidity)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this issue and really needed to get the array length on an already deployed contract. And of course I didn't deploy some nice `getCount()` function.

Here's my ***really terrible***, but working solution:

```
interface IExternalContract {
    function arrayToCount(uint idx) external view returns (address);
}

contract ArrayCounter {
    function getOfferCount(IExternalContract factory, uint start) public view returns (uint) {
        for (uint256 i = start; i < 10000; i++) {
            try factory.arrayToCount(i) returns (uint v) {
                start = i; // keep going
            } catch Error(string memory /*reason*/) {
                return i;
            } catch (bytes memory /*lowLevelData*/) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return start;
    }
}
```

To make this work for your contract you will need to change the array name `arrayToCount` and the return type of the array to whatever your is in the interface and in the `try` line.

You will need to pass it a starting index. For me, I knew my array was a little over 14k in length so I just passed in 14k. You should be able to get a close enough number by bisecting it down.

Comment: You could use something like a binary search to improve this a little.